# Having trouble with a Common Table Expression in SQL Server Adventureworks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, adventureworks

I have been coding this last problem all day and the file is due by tomorrow for my SQL Server database class.

I'm supposed to create a CTE that will create a temporary table of all female employees’ businessentityids and genders from the `Employee` table. Then return the businessentityid & gender from the CTE along with the employee first name, employee last name and person type from the person table where the person type is ‘EM’

My code I have simply converted all gender labels to F and changes PersonType to EM, this is almost becoming comical in how many times I have started over from scratch.

```
WITH cte_name2 AS 
(
    SELECT        
        FirstName, LastName, PersonType
    FROM            
        Person.Person
), cte_name1 AS
(
    SELECT        
        Gender, BusinessEntityID
    FROM            
        HumanResources.Employee
)
SELECT        
    cte_name1_1.BusinessEntityID, cte_name1_1.Gender, 
    cte_name2_1.FirstName, cte_name2_1.LastName, cte_name2_1.PersonType
FROM            
    cte_name1 AS cte_name1_1 
CROSS JOIN
    cte_name2 AS cte_name2_1
WHERE         
    (NOT (cte_name1_1.Gender LIKE N'M')) 
    AND (cte_name2_1.PersonType = N'EM')
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: you need to add BusinessEntityID to cte_name2, then the main query is an inner join between cte_name1 and cte_name2 on BusinessEntityId

Comment: I made the change you suggested but the CROSS JOIN will not change over to an INNER JOIN, the WHERE clause goes red.

Comment: You may need to add the join predicate ON : join ... ON  cte_name2_1.BusinessEntityID=cte_name1_1.BusinessEntityID, sorry I can't give you the complete solution because we aren't supposed to do that for homeworks

Answer (score 2):

The correct code is as follows...

```
WITH cte_name2 AS 
(
    SELECT        
        BusinessEntityID, FirstName, LastName, PersonType
    FROM            
        Person.Person
), cte_name1 AS
(
    SELECT        
        Gender, BusinessEntityID
    FROM            
        HumanResources.Employee
)
SELECT        
    cte_name1_1.BusinessEntityID, cte_name1_1.Gender, 
    cte_name2_1.FirstName, cte_name2_1.LastName, cte_name2_1.PersonType
FROM            
    cte_name1 AS cte_name1_1 
INNER JOIN
    cte_name2 AS cte_name2_1 ON cte_name2_1.BusinessEntityID = cte_name1_1.BusinessEntityID
WHERE        
    (cte_name1_1.Gender NOT LIKE N'M') 
    AND (cte_name2_1.PersonType = N'EM')
```

Turns out I was very close and Jayvee helped me out quite a bit!